# regex space or start of input, space or end of input

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match parts of a larger block of content and want to only match things at the start of the string or that are preceded by a space and I only want to match things that end at the end of string or are followed by a space. Unfortunately, my regex-fu is a bit too weak to figure this out on my own. Help me Stack Overflow, you are my only hope.

Basically these should all match "the-thing-to-match";

```
the-thing-to-match blah
blah the-thing-to-match
blah the-thing-to-match blah
```

Comment: Check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html too; it may (or may not) be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/(?:^| )the-thing-to-match(?: |$)/
```

EDIT: Remove quantifiers.

Comment: I think the problem is that he won't know the actual String that he's trying to match, just the position of the word.

Comment: No, that's right. I knew the string, I just needed to be sure it had spaces or start/end of string surrounding it.

Comment: Ah, now that I think about it, I suppose that would make sense.

Comment: you don't need *any* quantifiers on those spaces.